# Passing a value through $_GET with jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to pass a drop down value through `$_GET` with a jQuery function

Here is my code:

```
<div class="span2 text-right">
    <label class="f-s15">Choose Exam to take:</label>
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <select name="test_tag" id="test_tag">
    <?php
    foreach($array2 as $value2){ ?>
         <option value ="<?php echo $value2['_id']; ?>"><?php echo $value2['score_type']; ?> </option>
    <?php
       }
       ?>
   </select>
```

Here is my jQuery function:

```
function passTag() {
    var selectedvalue = jQuery('#test_tag').val();
    location.href="test_new.php?id="+selectedvalue;
}
```

Now when I `print_r($_GET)`, I don't get anything...

Comment: Do you call the passTag() function? What do you get if you manually open test_new.php?id=123 ?

Comment: i tried using onclick="passTag()" but it didn't work. it is working if i manually open it. but i need it sent through a click.

Comment: @ChristianBurgos do you see the test_new.php?id=something for the browser URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#test_tag").change(function(){
          var selectedvalue = jQuery('#test_tag').val();
          location.href="test_new.php?id="+selectedvalue;
       })
    })
```

Comment: do i still need the onclick on the button if i use this?

Comment: @ChristianBurgos selectedvalue = jQuery('#test_tag option:selected').val(); and check the URL in the browser

Comment: its working now! i just changed the jQuery("#test_tag").change(function()
to: jQuery("#take_exam").click(function() where take_exam is the id of my button

THANKS!